# Can't to clone Github repo over HTTP but SSH is ok (Assuming this is reason why Vundle not working)

Tags: git, vim, github, https, vundle

I am able to clone any repo to my PC through SSH in cygwin(x-server) but it is not working with HTTPS.

When I try:

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle
```

It stay in following forever and no error displayed.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git
Cloning into 'vundle'...
```

If I change HTTPS to SSH, it works.

The reason I worry about this is that I assume this is resaon why my Vundle not working.

I am using Vundle in my pc (whcih is working on my mac).

When I try `BundleInstall` or `PluginInstall`, it will stuck on plugins whatever is github repo and there is no error display. I think this situation is similar to when I try to clone repo.

Can anyone help me with this problem? 
Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that you have a firewall "protecting" you from the dangers of GitHub.  By default, SSH uses Port 22 and HTTPS uses Port 403.  I am not sure what utilities are included in cygwin, but you can test this by connecting to Port 22

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
$ telnet github.com 22
```

and Port 403

```
$ wget https://...
$ curl https://...
$ telnet github.com 403
```

I tend to have the opposite problem:  some of the servers I use allow outgoing connections on 403 but block 22.

Comment: I think this is the problem!!! I am not able to connect to google in terminal and which caused by my company firewall.  Thanks for your help!!!!!